# JTable w/ Mysql data need to have combo-box on JOINS

Tags: java, mysql, swing, join, jdbc

I use JTable to show result of MySQL SELECT query.
Such piece of table model code:

```
public void setDataSource(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {  
    data.clear(); 
    columnNames.clear(); 
    columnTypes.clear(); 

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData(); 
    int columnCount=rs md .getColumnCount(); 
    for (int i=0; i<columnCount; i++) { 
        columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i+1)); 
        Classtype =Cl as s.forName(rsmd.getColumnClassName(i+1)); 
        columnTypes.add(type); 
        // Here I need to detect is it a joined column
        // and if it is to set cell editor for this column to
        // a comboBox w/ data from joined table
    } 
    fireTableStructureChanged(); 
    while ( rs.next() ){ 
        ArrayListrow =new ArrayList(); 
        for ( int i=0; i<columnCount; i++) { 
            if(columnTypes.get(i) == String.class) 
             row.add(rs.getString(i+1)); 
            else 
             row.add(rs.getObject(i+1)); 
        } 
        synchronized(data){  
            data.add(row); 
            fireTableRowsInserted(data.size()-1,data .size()-1); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

As you see some columns may be gotten by JOIN operation, so I need to detect what actually are and set their editors to comboBoxes w/ possible values from JOINED table.
I think good manual or book about relation databases and usage them w/ swing would be fine too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've a base table, say A, joined with multiple other tables. Your requirement is to to show the columns coming out of the joined tables somewhat differently.

You can try [getTableName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName%28int%29) of ResultSetMetaData to get the name of the table to which the column belongs. Something like this:

```
int columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
System.out.println("Total Columns: "+columnCount);
for(int index = 1; index <= columnCount; index++){
    System.out.print("Column Name: "+resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(index));
    System.out.println("Table Name: "+resultSetMetaData.getTableName(index));
}
```

Since you already know the base table name, you can always use that to compare whether the current column that you're looking at belongs to the base table or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood, you are joining on two tables where there is a one to many relation between them. To make the discussion simpler, let's imagine that you have a table called department and a table called employee. Each department can have 0 or more employees. We want each row in the table to show a department and a combo box to select the employee.

Firstly, passing a ResultSet directly into your TableModel is not good practice. If your table is intended to show department data, your table model should accept a collection of Department objects.

So, you should iterate through your result set and create a collection of Department objects. Each department object could have a collection of Employee objects. When you have built your collection, you can then pass these into your TableModel.

This alone will not give you a combo box but it cleans things up and separates your concerns. To use a combo box as your cell editor, you need to do something like the following

```
TableColumn employeeColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(someIndex);

JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
comboBox.addItem("Chasing toddlers");
comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
comboBox.addItem("Teaching high school");
comboBox.addItem("None");
sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

The above code was taken from the Oracle Java tutorial here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html